# Is it possible for a flyback diode to increase solenoid temperature?

Tags: flyback, solenoid, heat-protection

I have a circuit with solenoids (rated at 12V 1A), and I am controlling them via an N Channel MOSFET with an overdrive function to keep them cool, since that is my main issue. Initially, I had put a flyback diode in parallel with the solenoid (IN4007), however while running tests, I noticed that the solenoid was significantly cooler when I took the flyback diode out. Why is this happening, and is it safe for my circuit (and solenoids, because they were quite expensive) to not have a flyback diode?

Comment: A diode alone just presents a very small flyback voltage across the coil, so the coil maintains the current longer (which you must also apparently be accounting for.) I agree with John that you are avalanching the NFETs without the diode. But for a simple experiment you might try a suitable zener in series with the 1N4007 to raise the voltage. It's a cheap experiment to do. Once you confirm/deny, then other questions can be addressed I think.

Answer (score 3):

Without the flyback diode, you are avalanching your FETs.  This causes a higher voltage across your solenoid, ramping down the current much faster.  Your solenoids are probably cooler.  However, you're dissipating a lot of power in your FETs during avalanche, which are probably getting much hotter.

FETs are not typically (with some exceptions) rated for repeated avalanche, so in the long run they may fail.  You could do something like using a power zener to clamp the solenoid voltage so that the current can ramp down quickly without avalanching the FET, but the zeners will be dissipating the Vz*Isolenoid on turn-off.

Comment: The minimum holding voltage dropped from 8.5 to 2.5 Volts with you suggestion, thanks so much!